# How to iterate over this type of Hashtable?

Tags: java, hashtable

I've this piece of code where I'm using extensions for keeping all created objects from each class.

```
public class ObjectPlus implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected static Hashtable<Class<? extends ObjectPlus>, Vector<ObjectPlus>> extensions = new Hashtable<>();

    public ObjectPlus()
    {
        Vector<ObjectPlus> extension= null;
        Class<? extends ObjectPlus> clasS = this.getClass();

        if(extensions .containsKey(clasS))
        {
            extension= extensions.get(clasS);
        }
        else
        {
            extension = new Vector<ObjectPlus>();
            extensions.put(clasS, extension);
        }
        extension.add(this);
    }
```

I've got also 3 other classes:

```
public abstract class Employee extends ObjectPlus{}
public class Guide extends Employee{}
public class Renovator extends Employee{}
```

and I'm adding each new Guide() and new Renovator() to this Hashtable.

I also have one fucntion in class Employee():

```
public void raise(double raiseAmount){}
```

in which I want to use method

```
public void setSalary(double newSalary) {
    this.salary = newSalary;
}
```

so then each object from both classes Guide and Renovator had their salary set to new value.

Have can I iterate properly over this Hashtable?

I was trying to use something like this:

```
    public void raise(double raiseAmount){
    Set<Class<? extends ObjectPlus>> setOfClasses = extensions.keySet();

    for (Class<? extends ObjectPlus> key : setOfClasses){
        extensions.get(key).setSalary(raiseAmount);
    }
}
```

but this doesn't work: "cannot resolve method 'setSalary(double)'

Comment: What do you want to do while iterating? You can just iterate over it like over any map.

Comment: I would like for each object from subclasses of Employee (Renovator and Guide) to be able to change their sallary through calling the method setSalary(double newSalary){ this.salary = newSalary} It's for the purpouse of presenting class method in UML project

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you were trying to call `raise()` on whole extent of Employee class. In the last code snippet you provided you are trying to call setSalary on all objects of all classes kept in ObjectPlus.extensions.

What I think you need instead is:

```java
public void raise(double raiseAmount){
    List<Employee> employees = (List<Employee>)extensions.get(Employee.class);

    for (Employee emp : employees){
        emp.setSalary(raiseAmount);
    }
}
```

Comment: With List<Employee> employees = extensions.get(Employee.class); I get incompatible types. If it's important, abstract class Employee extends ObjectPlus and both Renovator and Guide extend Employee class.

Comment: I've edited my answer to cast the result of `extensions.get(Employee.class)`, please try it now.

Answer (score 0):

extensions list element is not familiar with the setSalary method, you should cast it to the Employee object

((Employee)extensions.get(key)).setSalary(raiseAmount);